# How to check-in ( release, make it free) ArcGIS10.2 desktop license using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

There is a way to do this using ArcGIS license Server Administrator, but I need a command to use it in arcpy scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such arcpy command in ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your looking for [CheckInExtension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000003q000000)?

looks as simple as

```
arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")
```

(oops, answered too quickly) at least for extensions - the desktop license condition appears to be read only - more info [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000000z000000)